A short story about a haunted cellar in Paris in the Middle Ages
I read this short story at least 20 years ago, but it could be much older.
I read it in French, and it takes place in Paris, in the Middle Ages, in a street that used to be called "rue d'Enfer" (Hell's street).  Now it has been enlarged into a Boulevard called Denfert-Rochereau. But of course the story need not have been written when the name was still "rue d'Enfer", till 1878. Quite possibly, it was written only shortly before I read it. The old name is common knowledge, any contemporary author would have known that.
There was an abandoned building there, which was assumed to be haunted: every night a loud music was heard coming from it, together with a sound of bottles being knocked on each other or on hard surfaces.
During daytime, nothing was found. Indeed there was a cellar full of wine bottles, but apparently nothing uncanny about it. At night, nobody dared enter.
Finally a very large bounty was offered to anyone who dared enter at night. There was a soldier (well, probably rather what Paris had for policemen at that time, whatever they were called) who was in love with a wealthy woman, but she would not have considered him worthy of her. So he decided to take a chance to get rich so she'd marry him.
Het gets into the building at night and find that in the cellar, empty or broken bottles are making music while full bottles dance, floating in the air. He takes one of the full ones and gets out, telling everyone there is nothing to fear. So all the other soldiers/policemen/whatever go down and take out all the bottles with them.
The first one gets the bounty and marries his beloved one. They keep the bottle till their wedding party, and drink it. Shortly after that a son is born to them. His skin has the dark green colour of the glass wine bottles are made of. Maybe he also has horns, I am not quite sure. I don't remember the story telling what happened to all the other soldiers who drank the other bottles.

Sounds very de Maupassant.

@JamesMcLeod It is indeed a possibility. But do you know how many short stories he wrote ?

It seems like hundreds…

So if you have a more precise idea, please post it as an answer...

Plausible answer: La Maison Hantée de la Rue d'Enfer (The Haunted House on Hell's Street), a 1899 short story by G. Lenotre.
I say "plausible" because while the title and release date are certainly promising, I cannot find either a copy of this short story anywhere, or even a brief description.
The best I can find is the description for this 2011 fantasy anthology the story appears in:

Here, then, is the third anthology - from 1899 to 1931 - devoted to the detectives of Darkness, those investigators of the occult who respond with vigor to devious attacks from the beyond, and those specialists of the spirit identifiable by their purely psychic methods, but whose help is just as indispensable when the police and traditional medicine fail. [...]
As for the last two short stories, they are French stories with investigators who could not be more French, confronted with the occult, since the first is the famous Vidocq and the second, Christophe Rozès, a spiritualist whose services Paris enlists.

I guess the Vidocq one could be a match, both for the time frame and the fact that Vidocq was in the police.

However, that anthology was published in 2011 (so after you would have read it "20 years ago"), and does not state that the French stories were published for the first time, hence if it is that one, you would have read it elsewhere.
Here is everything I've tried to track it down:

I browsed through a lot of pictures of old Lenotre collections on AbeBooks, and among the ones I cannot find the list of stories of, the most promising book is "Dossiers de Police" ("Police Files"), which thus might or might not have been the collection you read it in;
I called a second-hand bookseller who has an original edition, to ask him if he could check whether the story appeared in this volume; but according to him it did not, unfortunately;
The bookseller told me to look on France's National Library archive online, but among G. Lenotre's publications, there was no collection containing that story;
Then again, the Library does not have all his anthologies, so it's possible the story was published in one they do not have.

Honestly, this whole thing baffles me. It's as if Lenotre either did not write that story, or it was published in a book so rare, you're among a dozen few who ever read it (if it is that story).

Found with the Google query rue d'enfer site:noosfere.org (hell's street site:noosfere.org), which brought up this page about the short story as included in the 2011 collection, but without any description of said story.

I'm too much of a penny-pincher to spend 15€ in buying the 2011 anthology to check, but the idea is starting to grow on me.

Well, neither the cover of the collection of Le Fantôme de Wild Harbor not that of Les Dossiers de Police evoke anything in my memory. But not all collections or anthologies can be listed... I don't remember Vidocq in my story, but it is not clear that he has to appear in your proposal, does he ? But since I am not familiar with the name Christophe Rozès, he might well have appeared without my remembering. So I will provisionally not accept your answer waiting for a better one, but if there is none, after the seven days of the bounty have expired, I will "manually" award it to you.

@Alfred like I said, I'm baffled. Maybe Vidocq only appears briefly and is not the main hero. Honestly, if the title itself was not that much of a "wink, wink" situation, I wouldn't even have looked twice at the text I quoted.

Really, if Vidocq had been mentioned, I'd have remembered it. Too famous to be forgotten. Your quote mentions two stories and two investigators. Maybe Vidocq is in the other story, and whatever his name is in mine (Rozès, OK, I can scroll up to find his name, but this one does not register)

I have just "manually" awarded you the 50 points of the bounty, to thank you for your efforts. But since I am not convinced by your answer I did not accept it. If you can find convincing arguments I'll not only accept it but add another 100 points bonus.
